# Reinstalled Ubuntu and WIndows won't start (Grub rescue)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2

I have a HD with basically two partitions: one for Windows 10, another one for Ubuntu; both used to run correctly. However, in the grub selection where I have to choose to which OS I'm going to boot, Ubuntu works perfectly, but Windows gives an error: "no such partition".

You may think I've deleted the Windows partition: no. I can acess all my files inside Windows, copy and paste them, etc. I've already tried some commands on Windows repair (through W10 iso on pendrive) and nothing. I tried all that stuff of ls to figure out the partition Windows is in and I wound up finding a partition with ex4 or something, the thing is I think it is probably Ubuntu and not WIndows partition...

I'm probably going over all this the wrong way, I'm new to Linux and I've never did dual boot before. Sorry if I'm not seeing something obvious here! :)

Comment: Hello and welcome. This forum is mainly for Ubuntu related questions. If your installation configuration took over the EFI partition and erased it then you may need to reinstall the bootloader. https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-pr/000124331/how-to-repair-the-efi-bootloader-on-a-gpt-hdd-for-windows-7-8-8-1-and-10-on-your-dell-pc

Comment: I would suggest you boot up into Ubuntu( even an installation media ) and get a clear picture of the partitions that currently exist in the disk. Get the information about the UUID of each partition. This value is "unique" (randomly generated) for each partition.

Comment: Grub merely detects the boot options and lists them. It seems the issue here is on the windows side.